# Regular Expression in Python3

Tags: python, regex

How can I search a string with pattern `"12 Apr 2018"` in Python and convert it into a date object in python.

Comment: what have you tried? Are you looking for this specific date or any date in this format?

Comment: So, I have an html snippet web-scrapped from a site. And I need to extract the date from the string which is in this format. I tried re.search but the pattern returns none.                     print(re.search(r'^[1-3]*[1-9]*\b[a-zA-Z]*\b[1-9]{4}',str_mydivs)"

Comment: try: `\b[1-3][1-9]\s+[a-zA-Z]*\s+[0-9]{4}\b`  https://regex101.com/r/clHalz/1

Answer (score 1):

If its in the format like "12 Apr 2018" then you might be better off using [strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior). You might need to use regex though if its surrounded by other page content.

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("12 Apr 2018", "%d %b %Y")
```

Which will give you back a datetime object like below

```
datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 12, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
\b[1-3][0-9]\s+[a-zA-Z]*\s+[1-9][0-9]{3}\b
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/clHalz/2)

It's based on you regex with some slight changes. I've replaced beginning/end of the line marks (`^$`)with word boundaries `\b`. I've added spaces (`\s+`) between date parts and I allowed zero in the day and year.

When you have it, you can use `strptime`, as Sam Collins suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the date is always in the format "(numerical day) (3-letter abbreviated month) (4-digit year)", the regex you want is `[0-9]{1,2}(?#any one digit or any two consecutive digits) [a-zA-Z]{3}(?#three letters) [0-9]{4}(?#four digits)`

The comments (the `(?#...)` bits) can, obviously, be omitted.

I'd also suggest using the `findall` (or `finditer`), rather than the `search`, function of the compiled regular expression object.

To turn the result(s) into a Python date object, I'd suggest Sam's answer - `time.strptime(result, "%d %b %Y")` - where '`result`' stores the matched str.

Alternatively, for the regex, if you want it to be even more specific (though it might still catch invalid dates, like February 30), you could use `([0-2][0-9]|3[01]) (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)(?#maybe make this bit case-insensitive, if you want) [0-9]{4}`